# Abrir este window.open em uma janela centralizada

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte script que pega todos os links de uma página e abre em uma janela, Como posso abrir o resultado em uma janela centralizada?

```
javascript: var w = window.open('', '', 'height=800, width=600');var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');var b = a.length; if(b != 0){ w.document.write('<h1> Lista de Links </h1> '); for (i = 0; i < b; i++){ w.document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + a[i] + '\'>' + a[i] + '</a>' + '</pre> ');}} else{ w.document.write('Nenhum link encontrado');}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pegue a largura da janela com `window.innerWidth`, subtraia pela largura da janela aberta (`600`) e divida por 2.

O resultado disso você coloca na propriedade `left` da janela aberta:

```
window.open('', '', 'height=800, width=600, left='+(window.innerWidth-600)/2);
```

---

Caso queira centralizar verticalmente também, é a mesma coisa, só que usando `window.innerHeight` com a propriedade `top`:

```
window.open('', '', 'height=800, width=600, left='+(window.innerWidth-600)/2+', top='+(window.innerHeight-800)/2);
```

Comment: Tem como centralizar Verticalmente também?

Comment: Acrescentei na resposta. :)

Comment: Show! Obrigado!